# Trying to install numpy with SIMD CPU Optimizations using python pip

Tags: python, numpy, pip, build, simd

I am trying to install numpy through pip with CPU optimizations but I am not sure if I am installing it with the optimizations correctly.

Based on the documentation [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/simd/build-options.html#supported-features) I am running this

`pip install --no-cache-dir --global-option=build --global-option="--cpu-baseline=sse3" --global-option="--cpu-dispatch=max -ssse3 -sse41 -popcnt -sse42 -avx -xop -fma4 -f16c -fma3 -avx2 -avx512f -avx512cd -avx512_knl -avx512_knm -avx512_skx -avx512_clx -avx512_cnl -avx512_icl -avx512_spr" numpy`

This gives me the output:

```
DEPRECATION: --build-option and --global-option are deprecated. pip 24.0 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to use --config-settings. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11859
WARNING: Implying --no-binary=:all: due to the presence of --build-option / --global-option. 
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.26.1.tar.gz (15.7 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 15.7/15.7 MB 55.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
  WARNING: Ignoring --global-option when building numpy using PEP 517
  Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) ... done
  Created wheel for numpy: filename=numpy-1.26.1-cp311-cp311-linux_x86_64.whl size=26811457 sha256=a57a2dd0a4f297f75ce0f0110601e4e69aa8da60e8e3e967ad1aa7ed3a383fff
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-3xaj9yt4/wheels/2a/39/b4/338b7162547e7d40b5f8db8d71f5c136f32ce4b00b5e078185
Successfully built numpy
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.26.1
```

Now, I am not sure if the CPU optimizations kicked in because of the line `WARNING: Ignoring --global-option when building numpy using PEP 517`

I tried installing with `--no-use-pep517`  but this results in the error
`ERROR: Disabling PEP 517 processing is invalid: project specifies a build backend of mesonpy in pyproject.toml`

so I cant build even with source using this option because numpy uses mesonpy to build, how can I get around this?

Comment: You might get more help with an issues post on the Numpy's Github (especially if this is a bug -- the exact commands provided in the doc must work).

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are no CPUs that support both AMD XOP (dropped in Zen 1 and later) and AVX-512.(new in Zen 4 for AMD).  If those are separate dynamic-dispatch possibilities then sure, but it's not very useful to enable XOP since only obsolete AMD Bulldozer-family CPUs have it.